# Why is $\operatorname{Log}(2z-3i)$ not well defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am looking at a complex analysis example in a textbook, it makes the following claim:

using the principal branch of Log, the domain of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is the set $\mathbb C \setminus \{(x, 0) \mid x \le 0\}$

Letting $z=x+iy$, it is easy to see that $2z-3i=2x + i(2y − 3)$

This means that $\operatorname{Log}(2z-3i)$ where Log is in the principle branch, is not well defined.

WHY IS IT NOT WELl DEFINED? Someone please help me out

Comment: Are you sure they specified a branch? Log without a specific branch is multi-valued. It looks like a branch cut is declared. Are they taking the principal branch $Log(z)$ to give arguments from $[-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: @zahbaz yeah in the principal branch, that's why I capitalized Log

Comment: Presumably because there's trouble along the half-line $x \leq 0$ and $y = 3/2$, since on this half-line, $2z - 3i$ isn't in the domain of Log. Strictly speaking, the book should have added something about the domain $U$ of $z \mapsto \operatorname{Log}(2z - 3i)$, and said "_$\operatorname{Log}(2z - 3i)$ is not well-defined in $U$_", since, for example, your function _is_ well-defined on the open unit disk, or the lower half-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ray $R:=\bigl\{-t+{3\over2} i\bigm|\>t\geq0\bigr\}\subset{\mathbb C}$ and define the domain $\Omega$ by $\Omega:={\mathbb C}\setminus R$. Then the function
$$f(z):={\rm Log}(2z-3i)\ ,$$
where ${\rm Log}$ denotes the principal value of the logarithm, is well defined and analytic on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

It reads to me the book wants you to consider the principle branch only, i.e. $\text{Log}(z)$, where $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{(x,0):x\leq 0\}$. Then, if we next consider $\text{Log}(2x+i(2y-3))=\text{Log}(2z-3i)$, where we are still using the principle branch, then that can't be well defined because you can access the region $x\leq 0$ which is not permitted. For example, consider the complex number $z=3/2i-t$, where $t\geq 0$. Then again nothing is said about the domain.